# Unable to launch safari in simulator using appium xcuitest

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

I'm automating wb application in iOS simulator v10.0 using appium xcuitest v1.6 but I'm unable to launch the safari with the url mentioned in the code. Getting following exception.Please help.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'TVMATP310436M', ip: '192.168.1.116', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:47)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:114)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.(IOSDriver.java:81)
    at com.jcp.setup.SetUpAppium.main(SetUpAppium.java:29)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 0.0.0.0:4723 failed to respond
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'TVMATP310436M', ip: '192.168.1.116', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 0.0.0.0:4723 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:133)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
    ... 12 more

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather uninstall and install appium 1.6.4 by using these commands:

npm uninstall appium
npm install -g appium@1.6.4

There were issues related to Safari with earlier appium versions.